# how to simulate java card applet with Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, smartcard, javacard

I  am new to Java Card Programming (with netbeans). I did everything in [the Java Card Development Quick Start page](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/java-card.html) page and I created a classic card applet and tried simulate it. But when I try to simulate and send a command on device console, it sends an error

> `"Connection refused: connect".`

I didn't understand, what is wrong.

any suggestions?

here it's screen shot:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i solve the problem...

1. step;
   [image: i have 2 device]

i have 2 devices

2.step;
[image: i selected bundled java card 3.0.2 runtime device..]

and i selected bundled java card 3.0.2 runtime device..

3.step;
[image: and it return back to my APDU message]

and it return back to my APDU message..

Comment: Thanks for reporting back Savas, you can accept your own answer after a while.